# Prove that if UT is onto $R^l$, then U must be onto $R^l$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

**My Attempt:**

Claim: Let $T:R^n$


→
$R^m$ and $U:R^m$


→$R^l$ be linear transformations. If UT is onto $R^l$, then U must be onto $R^l$.

Proof (by contrapositive): Suppose $U$ is not onto $R^l$, then 
∃
$y$
∈
$R^l$ s.t. $U(x)$ 
≠
$y$  ∀
$x$
∈ $R^m$. Let $T(z)=x$ for $z$
∈
$R^n$ and $x$ 
∈
$R^m$. Then 
$U$
∘
$T(z)$
 $=$ $U(T(z))=U(x)$≠$y$

⟹ 


$UT$ is not onto $R^l$. Therefore, if $UT$ is onto $R^l$, then $U$ must be onto $R^l$ as claimed.

Comment: For $x\in R^n$, $U \circ T(x)$ is a single vector in $R^l$ and is not a subspace. Do you mean $U\circ T (R^n) := Im (U\circ T)$?

Comment: My bad, fixed it. Please check now. Thanks.